# Negative eccentricity in orbital motion

Tags: orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

$e=0$ represents circular motion

$0<e<1$ for elliptical

$e=1$ for parabolic motion

$e>1$ for hyperbolic

Does negative eccentricity ($e<0$) have any meaning too?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2138638/significance-of-negative-eccentricity

Answer (score 2):

eccentricity is just a ratio of two lengths  (more accurately distance) for a traversing point,one measured from a particular point and another is from a particular line. You can never get negative eccentricity as lengths are always positive.